# Can't access OAuth Access token method while doing Github Login with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

According to Firebase documentation to get OAuth access token on successful login, we can get it from the getCredential() method like: authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken()

Code: According to firebase:

```
firebaseAuth
.startActivityForSignInWithProvider(/* activity= */ this, provider.build())
.addOnSuccessListener(
    new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
        // User is signed in.
        // IdP data available in
        // authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo().getProfile().
        // The OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
        // authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken().
      }
    })
.addOnFailureListener(
    new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        // Handle failure.
      }
    });
```

But, when I try to access the token like that, it just simply says that the method doesn't exist.

```
 pendingResultTask
    ?.addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->
        val username = authResult.additionalUserInfo?.username
        val accessToken = authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken()

        Toast.makeText(
            activity,
            "username: $username, accessToken: $accessToken",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        navigateToHomeScreen()
    }
    ?.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Toast.makeText(
            activity,
            "Something Went Wrong: ${exception.message}",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }
```

here in this code, I can't use `getAccessToken()` method, error: Unresolved reference

Why I am not able to access the `getAccessToken()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AuthResult#getCredential()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult#getCredential()) method returns an object of type [AuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthCredential), and as far as I can see, there is no getAccessToken() method present there.

However, there is a commented line there that says:

> The **OAuth** access token can also be retrieved.

So you should take a look into [OAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/OAuthCredential) class, which exposes a [getAccessToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/OAuthCredential#getAccessToken()) method.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I looked into it and found that the issue for me is that onSuccessListener should be of type OAuthCredential according to the docs, but for me it's of type AuthCredential.
I'm even using the same OAuthProvider object that is mentioned in the docs

    `val oAuthProvider: OAuthProvider.Builder = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("github.com")`

Comment: So have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to fix it now. I have to cast credential.accessToken as OAuthCredential and then get the access token from there. This has been updated in the iOS documentation on firebase, but it still needs to be updated for the Android docs

Answer (score 0):

```
// token from Apple with authResult.getCredential().
OAuthCredential authCredential= (OAuthCredential) authResult.getCredential();
```

**Call below method to get the access token**

```
String accessToken=authCredential.getAccessToken()
```